# What is the proper way to to get dot product of two N-D (3-D) matrices using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I want to get dot product of two arrays along the batch dimension. `np.dot` gave a super weird result. Let suppose I have a batch of size 2. So what would be the proper way to get the results?

```
X = np.random.randn(2,3,4)
X_t = np.transpose(X,axes=[0,2,1]) # shape now is [2,4,3]
np.matmul(X,X_t) # shape is [2,3,3]
np.dot(X,X_t) # shape is [2,3,2,3] SUPER Weird
np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',X,X_t) # Dimension as [2,3,3] Same as Matmul()
```

What is the correct way of matrix multiplication for conditions like these?

Comment: `dot` doesn't do 'batches'.  That's why `matmul` was added.  The correct way is the one that gives the desired result.

Comment: And what is the **desired** result in my case? I mean, is there any general formula?

Comment: Have you read the docs of those 3 functions?  What do you expect us to add?

Comment: @hpaulj I  am asking what is the proper way to multiply 2 3-d matrices? Matrix `X,Y` are [batch,sentence_length, word_embedding_dim]. So how do you multiply properly? I am trying to code [Transformer architecture](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/06/understanding-transformers-nlp-state-of-the-art-models/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` operator. It reduces the first (0th) dimention.

`Matmul` for other dims.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(2, 3, 4)
x_t = np.transpose(x, axes=[0, 2, 1])  # shape now is [2,4,3]

wrong = np.dot(x, x_t)  # shape is [2,3,2,3] SUPER Weird
res = x @ x_t

print(res.shape)
print(wrong.shape)
```

out:

```
(2, 3, 3)
(2, 3, 2, 3)
```

Comment: So  if Matrix X,Y are `[batch,sentence_length, word_embedding_dim]` , and I transpose `y` just like above, it'll give me a `dot product` of EACH `Word` to its sentence , per sentence in batch? Right? I am trying to implement [Scaled Dot Product Attention for transformer just like it is done in the link](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#scaled_dot_product_attention)